# Не работает приведение типов по индексу в массивах?

Tags: c#

```
ToVideoArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32((SliderArray[s1]));
```

Не работает приведение типов по индексу в массивах, выдает ошибку, что нет явного приведения типов, хотя я его указал:

> Ошибка    CS0266  Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "double" в "int".
>   Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение
>   типов).

Пытался и так:

```
 ToVideoArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32((SliderArray[s1]));
```

Уточнение: `SliderArray[s1]` возвращает `double`

`s1` – типа double

`ToVideoArray` – массив типа `int`

`i` – индекс типа `int`

Comment: `(int)Convert.ToInt32(...)` - кастим `int` к `int`?

Comment: `SliderArray[(int)s1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индексатор в массиве принимает `int`. В данном случае

```
SliderArray[s1]
```

идет попытка передать `double`

> s1 - типа double

Следовательно, перед передачей, нужно привести эту переменную к `int`, например явно: `(int)s1`

В итоге должно выйти

```
ToVideoArray[i]= Convert.ToInt32(SliderArray[(int)s1]);
```